# Background image not loading on GoDaddy

Tags: css, image, hosting, godaddy-api

I uploaded my website code to GoDaddy for hosting but the background image is not loading. The background image is in the folder 'images' on GoDaddy.

Background image is listed in my CSS file as:

```
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), 
    url(/images/background-image.jpg);
```

Website: [tretuser.com](http://tretuser.com)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: background-image working fine on given url

Comment: @Aman: really? Do you see a picture of a girl? I wonder why the background image doesn't load when I go to tretuser.com. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Yes bro, it's showing fine on my end

Comment: For me too.
Check in the developer tools, network tab if it's loading the image.

Comment: I voted to close this question because it is not a programming question and it is off-topic on Stack Overflow. Non-programming questions about your website should be asked on [webmasters.se]. However, given the comments, you may not actually have an issue, so you only need to re-ask if there is a new problem.

Comment: What browser/system are you using? The girl appears in Edge on Windows10 OK for me.